# Change sign-up form depending on the drop down-menu?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, css, javascript-objects

Thank you for taking your time to help me figure out this problem, I'm a beginner in javascript, and I can't figure out how to create a dropdown menu that activates different sign up forms depending on what the user chooses.

So in my code I have 3 different sign up forms: Plumber, Contractor, and Electrician. When the user selects one of them, the sign up form should change to a plumber sign up form or electrician sign up form, etc.

**Please help me figure out why my javascript is not showing the other signup forms?**

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/d0e6t7o4/1/

HTML:

Plumber
                        Contractor
                        Electrician

```
<div id="plumber">
            <!-- Register Form -->

    <p>Plumber Signup</p>
            <div class="user_register1">



                <form>
                    <label>Plumbers Name</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    <br />

                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" />
                    <br />

                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" />
                    <br />


                    <div class="action_btns">

                        <div class="one_half last"><a href="#" class="btn btn_red">Register</a></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
</div>
</div>  

<div id="Contractor">

    <p>Contractor Signup</p>

            <div class="user_register2">

                <form>
                    <label>Contractor Name</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    <br />

                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" />
                    <br />

                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" />
                    <br />


                    <div class="action_btns">

                        <div class="one_half last"><a href="#" class="btn btn_red">Register</a></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="electrician">

    <p>Electrician Signup</p>
            <div class="user_register3">

                <form>
                    <label>Electrician Name</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    <br />

                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" />
                    <br />

                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" />
                    <br />


                    <div class="action_btns">

                        <div class="one_half last"><a href="#" class="btn btn_red">Register</a></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
</div>


</div>

</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var select = $( '#dropdown' );

function showTab( name ) {
  name = '#' + name;
  $( 'div' ).not( name ).hide();
  $( name ).show();
}

select.change( function() {
  showTab( $( this ).val() );   
});

showTab( select.val() );
```

And CSS:

```
.user_register label {display: block; margin-bottom:5px;}
.user_register input[type="text"], .user_register input[type="email"], .user_register input[type="password"] {display: block; width:90%; padding: 10px; border:1px solid #DDD; color:#666;}
.user_register input[type="checkbox"] {float:left; margin-right:5px;}
.user_register input[type="checkbox"]+label {float:left;}

.user_register .checkbox {margin-bottom: 10px; clear: both; overflow: hidden;}

/* User Login Form */
.user_login {display: block;}
.user_login label {display: block; margin-bottom:5px;}
.user_login input[type="text"], .user_login input[type="email"], .user_login input[type="password"] {display: block; width:90%; padding: 10px; border:1px solid #DDD; color:#666;}
.user_login input[type="checkbox"] {float:left; margin-right:5px;}
.user_login input[type="checkbox"]+label {float:left;}

.user_login .checkbox {margin-bottom: 10px; clear: both; overflow: hidden;}
.forgot_password {display:block; margin: 20px 0 10px; clear: both; overflow: hidden; text-decoration: none; color:#ED6347;}


.btn {padding:10px 20px; background: #F4F4F2;}
.btn_red {background: #ED6347; color: #FFF;}

.btn:hover {background: #E4E4E2;}
.btn_red:hover {background: #C12B05;}

a.btn {color:#666; text-align: center; text-decoration: none;}
a.btn_red {color: #FFF;}

.one_half {width:50%; display: block; float:left;}
.one_half.last {width:45%; margin-left:5%;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure the capitalization is the same in the `<option>` `value`s and the `<div>` `id`s, or it won't work.

For example, in your `<select>`, you have:

```
<option value="plumber" selected="selected">Plumber</option>
```

And you have the div:

```
<div id="Plumber">
```

This would not work.

---

Secondly, you are hiding **all** the `<div>`s besides the container ones (basically the whole form). You need to hide **only** the other container `<div>`s.

To do this, I added the class `formDiv` to each of these containing `<div>`s, and **only** hid those:

```
$( 'div.formDiv' ).not( "#" + name ).hide();
```

---

See working example at [JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/d0e6t7o4/3/).

Comment: @user3771570 I'm glad it helped!